# How do I create an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project with a JSF Facet that specifies version 2.3?

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I am using Eclipse Oxygen 3. When configuring a JavaServer Faces facet, the highest version number that can be chosen is 2.2. What is the correct way to tell Eclipse that I am using version 2.3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *What is the correct way to tell Eclipse that I am using version 2.3?*

You can't. You basically need to upgrade Eclipse to a newer version. But as it isn't there yet, it ends here.

For now, just pick 2.2 and edit afterwards the `faces-config.xml` to specify 2.3. It goes as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
    version="2.3">

    <!-- Config here. -->
</faces-config>
```

That's basically it. This works because Eclipse is merely a code editor and the JSF facet basically instructs Eclipse to autogenerate some files (such as `faces-config.xml`) and installs the `FacesServlet` and adds JSF specific builders and validators to the project. In other words, even with a JSF 2.2 facet, you can develop, build and run a JSF 2.3 project in Eclipse just fine.